# Gitlab 500 error when adding/removing SSH key

Tags: gitlab, ssh-keys

When I try to add a SSH key to Gitlab 7.3.1 on Ubuntu 14.04 it doesn't work. I get an 500 internal server error and the site is extremly slow.

On refresh nothing is added and when I try again, same problem over and over again.

Trying to read the logs:

```
# tail -f /var/log/gitlab/gitlab-rails/production.log
```

Parameters: {“utf8″=>”✓”, “authenticity_token”=>”nKCheVvcyuhTrKUTrWbin9VOYpVPJEWk6lAJO63Lu9o=”, “key”=>……………………………….

…………………………………………….

………………………………………………………………….”}}
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 137ms

Errno::ENOMEM (Cannot allocate memory – ssh-keygen):
lib/gitlab/popen.rb:23:in `popen’
app/models/key.rb:78:in`block in generate_fingerpint’
app/models/key.rb:75:in `generate_fingerpint’
app/controllers/profiles/keys_controller.rb:20:in`create’

How to fix this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Probably because Gitlab can't allocate enough memory,

You need to create a swap file.
Try the following steps to see if this works:

```
#dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=2048k count=1000
#mkswap /swapfile
#swapon /swapfile
#swapon -s
#chown root:root /swapfile
#chmod 0600 /swapfile
#echo 10 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
#echo vm.swappiness = 10 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf
```

If this works you can make it permanent by editing the following file:
    #nano /etc/fstab

add this line :

```
/swapfile       none    swap    sw      0       0
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much! This solved many 500 Errors of my Omnibus Installation of gitlab-ce! Thank you so much, this was driving me crazy...

Comment: Your welcome! I also added a blog; http://chilion.nl/gitlab-500-error-when-addingremoving-ssh-key/

Comment: Any chance someone could comment the above code to give a general idea of what's happening? It would save us a lot of time looking up and interpreting arguments for each of those commands. It totally worked for me and I can even see the result in `top` but I hate not knowing why! Thanks, in advance.